# How can I connect more than 7 devices via bluetooth LE simultaneously?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to connect 10 drones (rolling spider drone) to my Mac via bluetooth LE and control them at the same time. Is there anyway that I can use Arduino to do it? Or any other way? The bluetooth device can connect to 5-7 slaves at the most.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: I've already connected 5 devices to my mac, i just want to know if there is a way to connect more than 5 ( if its possible ). and i will try to do it..

Comment: Is this a programming issue, or operating system issue? You may have posted this to the wrong StackExchange site.